# Quadratic Programming in python using data from octave

Tags: python, matlab, octave, cvxopt, quadprog

I'm in the midst of converting parts of a MATLAB program in to Python and Octave.

I am using Octave to generate two matrices, then importing those matrices in to python using `oct2py`. The root of my problem are these lines in MATLAB (`H_combined` and `f_combined` below)

```
handles.options =optimset('algorithm','interior-point-convex','Display','off','TolFun',1e-15,'TolX',1e-10,'MaxFunEvals', 1E5);

handles.x_ridge_combined = quadprog(H_combined, f_combined, [], [], [], [], handles.lb_re, handles.ub_re, handles.x_re_0, handles.options);
```

Currently, I'm looking for a solution in either Python or Octave that would produce a similar output to no avail.

I have attempted to use `quadprog` from Octave's `optim` however I get an output of `120, 1, 1, 1, ..., 1` on `x_ridge_combined`, rather than an assortment of float values which I would expect. I have verified that `H_combined` and `f_combined` are exactly the same as the when run in MATLAB, but I suppose `quadprog` in Octave does not work the same.

After trying an Octave approach, I attempt to import the values into Python to try using the `quadprog` package.

Trying `quadprog`,

```
print(quadprog.solve_qp(H,f))
```

yields the error

```
ValueError: Buffer has wrong number of dimensions (expected 1, got 2)
```

The types and shapes of `H` and `f` are as follows:

```
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> #H
(123, 123)
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> #f
(1, 123)
```

Does anybody know why I may be getting these errors? Or any other suggestions on to how to translate that line from MATLAB?

Comment: On a quick read, I think you'd be better off giving some more info. The point of divergence between your matlab original code and you combined python/octave substitute seems to be quadprog. Given exactly the same inputs, none of the python/octave quadprog produces the same output as matlab. Is that correct?
Could you post the inputs you are using?
If these are large data sets, could you produce a smaller example that produces the same errors?
I know it takes some work...

Comment: Is the quadprog line in matlab exactly the same as in octave?

Comment: Try using the documented example in both matlab and octave to check the results
https://octave.sourceforge.io/optim/function/quadprog.html

Comment: Check this thread on a difference matlab-octave, although I am not sure it is your case https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/help-octave/2015-09/msg00120.html

Comment: Or check these other examples to compare https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html

Answer (score 1):

Try using [cvxopt_quadprog](https://github.com/nolfwin/cvxopt_quadprog). The author claims it imitates MATLAB `quadprog`, and it should accept arguments the same way:

```
def quadprog(H, f, L=None, k=None, Aeq=None, beq=None, lb=None, ub=None):
    """
    Input: Numpy arrays, the format follows MATLAB quadprog function: https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/quadprog.html
    Output: Numpy array of the solution
    """
```

Most probably the error is because your `f` is matrix [1x123], while it should be vector of length [123]. You can try to reshape it :

```
f = f.reshape(f.shape[1])
```

Comment: I am d'accord with the the `reshape` solution. Should work for the original code =)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, although the problem with cvxopt_quadprog is that it is considerably slower for large iterative optimizations of time series as it checks each time if the problem is PSD, which is why I was hoping to make use of quad_prog, which has been proven to be much faster. Ref: https://github.com/stephane-caron/qpsolvers

Answer (score 0):

Although it is a bit off scope, I want to bring the project [NLopt](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) into play. As the acronym suggests, it tackles nonlinear optimization but with plenty of [global/local, derivative-free/with explicit derivatives algorithms](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/). The reason, why I want to mention it is, that it has an interface for MATLAB, Octave + Python (and C/C++,...). So it makes it very easy to reproduce the solutions in different languages (that is why I came across it); plus, the algorithms are actually faster than the MATLAB-native ones (this is my own experience).

For your problem, I would go with [BOBYQA](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/#bobyqa) (bounded optimization by quadratic optimization or [SLSQP](https://nlopt.readthedocs.io/en/latest/NLopt_Algorithms/#slsqp) (sequential least-squares quadratic programming). However, you will have to write a cost function rather than hand over matrices

[The installation is easy via pip](https://pypi.org/project/nlopt/)

```
pip install nlopt
```

do a little check

```
import nlopt
# run quick test. Look for "Passed: optimizer interface test"
nlopt.test.test_nlopt()
```

some quick code on how to use the optimization:

```
import numpy as np
import nlopt

obj = nlopt.opt(nlopt.LN_BOBYQA,5)
obj.set_min_objective(fnc)

obj.set_lower_bounds(lb)
obj.set_upper_bounds(ub)

def fnc(x, grad):

        """
        The return value should be the value of the function at the point x, 
        where x is a NumPy array of length n of the optimization parameters 
        (the same as the dimension passed to the constructor).

        In addition, if the argument grad is not empty, i.e. grad.size>0, then 
        grad is a NumPy array of length n which should (upon return) be set to 
        the gradient of the function with respect to the optimization parameters 
        at x. That is, grad[i] should upon return contain the partial derivative , 
        for , if grad is non-empty.
        """
        H = np.eye(len(x)) # extampe matrix

        cost = 0.5*x.transpose().dot( H.dot(x) )
        return float(cost) # make sure it is a number

xopt = obj.optimize(x0)
```

In MATLAB you just need to add the DLLs to you path. I wrote a short wrapper for BOBYQA to mimic the interface of MATLAB (in case, you want to check it out in both languages =P -- let me know, I am using it more often in MATLAB... as the wrapper probably shows^^):

```
function [x_opt, fval, exitflag] = BOBYQA(fnc,x0,lb,ub, varargin)
% performes a constrained, derivative-free local optimization
%
% --- Syntax:
% x_opt = BOBYQA(fnc,x0,lb,ub)
% x_opt = BOBYQA(...,'MaxEval',10)
% x_opt = BOBYQA(...,'MaxTime',5)
% [x_opt, fval] = BOBYQA(...)
% [x_opt, fval, exitflag] = BOBYQA(...)
% 
% --- Description:
% x_opt = BOBYQA(fnc,x0,lb,ub)  takes a function handle 'func', an initial 
%               value 'x0' and lower and upper boundary constraints 'lb' 
%               and 'ub' as input. Performes a constrained local 
%               optimization using the algorithm BOBYQA from Powell 
%               http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/na/NA_papers/NA2009_06.pdf.
%               Returns the optimal value 'x_opt'.
% x_opt = BOBYQA(...,'MaxEval',10)optional input parameter that defines the
%               maximum number of evaluations.
% x_opt = BOBYQA(...,'MaxTime',5) optional input parameter that defines the
%               maximum allowed time in seconds for the optimization. This 
%               is a soft constraint and may be (slightly) broken.
% [x_opt, fval] = BOBYQA(...) seconds return value is the optimal function 
%               value.
% [x_opt, fval, exitflag] = BOBYQA(...) third return value is the exitflag,
%               see function NLoptExitFlag().
% 
% ------------------------------------------------------------------- 2017

% NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA

% --- parse input
IN = inputParser;
addParameter(IN,'MaxEval',10000, @(x)validateattributes(x,{'numeric'},{'positive'}));
addParameter(IN,'MaxTime',60, @(x)validateattributes(x,{'numeric'},{'positive'}));
parse(IN,varargin{:});

% generic success code: +1
%      stopval reached: +2
%         ftol reached: +3
%         xtol reached: +4
%      maxeval reached: +5
%      maxtime reached: +6
% generic failure code: -1
%    invalid arguments: -2
%        out of memory: -3
%     roundoff-limited: -4

    % set options
    opt = struct();
    opt.min_objective = fnc;
    opt.lower_bounds = lb;
    opt.upper_bounds = ub;



    % stopping criteria
    opt.maxtime = IN.Results.MaxTime; % s  % status = +6
%     opt.fc_tol = FncOpt.STOP_FNC_TOL*ones(size(ParInit)); % +3
%     opt.xtol_rel = FncOpt.STOP_XTOL_REL; % +4
%     opt.xtol_abs = FncOpt.STOP_XTOL_ABS*ones(size(ParInit)); % +4
    opt.maxeval = IN.Results.MaxEval; % status = +5

    % call function
    opt.algorithm = 34;% eval('NLOPT_LN_BOBYQA');

    t_start = tic;
    [x_opt, fval, exitflag] = nlopt_optimize(opt,x0);
    dt = toc(t_start);
    fprintf('BOBYQA took %.5f seconds | exitflag: %d (%s)\n',dt,exitflag,NLoptExitFlag(exitflag))
end

function txt = NLoptExitFlag(exitflag)
% generic success code: +1
%      stopval reached: +2
%         ftol reached: +3
%         xtol reached: +4
%      maxeval reached: +5
%      maxtime reached: +6
% generic failure code: -1
%    invalid arguments: -2
%        out of memory: -3
%     roundoff-limited: -4

switch exitflag
    case 1
        txt = 'generic success code';
    case 2
        txt = 'stopval reached';
    case 3
        txt = 'ftol reached';
    case 4
        txt = 'xtol reached';
    case 5
        txt = 'maxeval reached';
    case 6
        txt = 'maxtime reached';
    case -1
        txt = 'generic failure code';
    case -2
        txt = 'invalid arguments';
    case -3
        txt = 'out of memory';
    case -4
        txt = 'roundoff-limited';
    otherwise
        txt = 'undefined exitflag!';
end
end
```